# Optical Mark Reader (OMR ) - JAVA

Tags: java, omr

Unable to start with a OMR reader application . Tried this [Udai OMr](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~aseth/udai/OMRProj/README.html) , But I am getting NullPointerException . Any Suggestions ?

```
D:\OmR\ java -cp "dist/OMRProj.jar;dist/lib/jiu.jar" omrproj.ProcessTemplate [template-filename]
at omrproj.ImageUtil.readImage(ImageUtil.java:28)
    at omrproj.ProcessForm.main(ProcessForm.java:27)
```

Comment: You are getting [NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) because for some reason the source of the image is bull. Check your code to find the possible place where you can loose the information related to image source. Or provide more code to see where the problem is happening

Comment: I have provided the source link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path of template images was wrong .